# Why can't I delete the entries file in a .svn directory from the command line?

Tags: svn, macos

First this is all done on  Mac OS X, ver 10.6.4

I copied a file tree, which included some java code that had been checked out of subversion. I wanted to delete all the .svn files in that tree. So I used the following command:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -fr .svn {} \;
```

And I got messages like this:

```
rm: ./repository/entity/.svn: Directory not empty
```

I looked in the directory and it looks like this:

```
$ ls -ld .
-r--r--r--  1 tgia  staff  1250 Aug 13 10:48 entries
```

And the parent directory for that file looks like this:

```
$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x  4 tgia  staff  136 Aug 20 16:55 .
```

ok, change the permissions on the file:

```
$ chmod u+w entries 
chmod: Unable to change file mode on entries: Operation not permitted
```

I don't get it, what's up with these files? Nothing I try with chmod seems to change the file permissions. The file ownership is correct. I am tgia. WTF? Even root can't change them.

```
$ sudo chmod u+w entries
Password:
chmod: Unable to change file mode on entries: Operation not permitted
```

Luckily root can delete them...

Comment: Why do you want to delete all the `.svn` dirs here?  `svn export` is a cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I addition to the usual rwx flags, OSX has a special UCHG flag.  This may be what you ran into.

In the user interface you can set or unset it in the Get Info window.  Click on the "Locked" checkbox.

On the command line use `chflags uchg filename` to set it.  Or `chflags nouchg filename` to unset.

Files with the read-only flag set on Windows will show up with the uchg flag set when exchanged via smb.  That's how I ran into it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your command line is exactly correct. Try:

```
find . -name .svn | xargs rm -rf
```

I think your command line will try to execute commands such as:

```
rm -fr .svn subdir1/.svn
rm -fr .svn subdir2/.svn
```

That is, you've got an extra `.svn` in there.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -name .svn -exec rm -fr .svn {} \;`

should be

`find . -name .svn -exec rm -fr {} \;`

Comment: Yeah, actually I mistyped, the command I used was 

find . -name .svn -exec rm -fr {} \;

and that wouldn't delete the entries...
It was only when I got to the point where I was deleting the files named entry as root that it worked. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

I had to unset the uappnd flag as well as the uchg flag too, i.e.:

```
find .svn -type f |xargs sudo chflags nouappnd,nouchg
```

Comment: I've taken to removing all of these extended flags using "chflags -R 0000 /path/to/whereever"